# Qu'est-ce que l'abréviation « dans Esn. » ?

Tags: abréviations, dictionnaires

En lisant la section étymologie de l'entrée [*« pêche* »](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/p%C3%AAche) au *Trésor de la Langue Française Informatisé*, on y voit:

> d) 1960 avoir la pêche «avoir le moral» (**ds Esn.**, prob. d'apr. le
>   suivant);

J'ai recherché comme acronyme [ici](http://acronymes.info/), et ce qui en ressort sont des numéros d'enregistrement électronique, des réseaux commutés etc. Mais il s'agit plutôt fort probablement d'une abréviation. J'ai recherché ce sigle dans les pages d'introduction du *Grand Larousse de la langue française* pour fins de comparaison mais sans succès. Qu'est-ce que c'est que ce  « *dans Esn.* » ?

Comment: Les dictionnaires abrègent souvent les noms d'auteurs et les titres. Ces abréviations ne sont pas normalisées, à ma connaissance. La liste des abréviations est imprimée au début ou à la fin du dictionnaire, pour le TLF elle n'a pas l'air d'être en ligne. Je ne sais pas qui est Esn.

Comment: @Gilles Merci, en effet je n'ai pas vu de tel tableau des abréviations dans la section Aide du tlfi - et me suis promis de leur écrire à ce sujet. En plus je comprends mal pourquoi quand la référence à l'auteur vise une citation, on a le nom de famille complet, mais pas quand on "commente" comme dans l'extrait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probablement l'un des ouvrages de [Gaston Esnault](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaston_Esnault), le [Dictionnaire historique des argots français](http://www.languefrancaise.net/Argot/DHAF)

Comment: Merci! Il y a beaucoup de chances en effet; en plus, le _suivant_ auquel l'extrait réfère est un document intitulé _L'Arg. de l'École de l'air_, dont le sujet est familier à M. Esnault puisque comme le mentionne l'article wiki, il avait rédigé un dictionnaire de l'argot militaire de la 1ère guerre mondiale. Gaston Esnault(1874-1971).