# L'abréviation « ds Quem. DDL t. # » ?

Tags: abréviations

Au *Trésor de la langue française informatisé* (TLFi), les entrées se terminent souvent par une section sur l'étymologie (par exemple le mot [*kayak*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/kayak)). On a déjà [remarqué](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7381/a-list-of-all-abbreviations-used-in-dictionaries) l'absence d'une liste des abréviations utilisées dans ce dictionnaire et on a [mentionné](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/12943/quest-ce-que-labr%C3%A9viation-dans-esn#comment23657_12943) qu'il n'y avait pas de norme dans l'emploi des abréviations en général. Dans plusieurs entrées au dictionnaire (ainsi que dans 16k [résultats](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ds%20Quem.%20DDL%20t.%2021%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=8u6gVZ31IoP2-QH2orfoCA#q=%22ds%20Quem.%20DDL%22) sur le moteur Google) on a :

> ds Quem. *DDL* t. [numéro du tome; et il y en a au moins 21 si on se fie sur *kayak*]

On dit qu'on retrouve un texte (par ex. *Journal des missions évangéliques* à kayak), ou sa référence, dans un recueil ou un dictionnaire. On y réfère sans doute par le nom de l'auteur suivi de l'acronyme désignant l’œuvre vu l'italique *DDL*. Mais en faisant une recherche sur l'[acronyme](http://www.acronymfinder.com/DDL.html) ou les noms d'auteurs commençant par *Quem.*, il y a des interférences avec des emplois technologiques, militaires, le latin, et tous les [dictionnaires](http://www.lexilogos.com/etymologie.htm) qui se citent les uns les autres. Le nom de plusieurs dictionnaires pourrait former l'acronyme *DDL* mais combien de ces dictionnaires ont 20+ tomes et ont un auteur dont le nom commence par Quem. ?

À quelle œuvre et à quel auteur cette abréviation fait-elle exactement référence ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Selon [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=DDL&oldid=114803029) et [le catalogue de la Bibliothèque nationale de France](http://catalogue.bnf.fr/servlet/biblio?idNoeud=1&ID=34225915&SN1=0&SN2=0&host=catalogue), il s'agit d'une collection dont le titre principal est « *Matériaux pour l'histoire du vocabulaire français* », et le sous-titre « *Datations et documents lexicographiques* », qui correspond à ce mystérieux « DDL ».

M. Bernard Quemada en est l'éditeur.

Comment: Ce fut avec grand plaisir. Un simple [retour de faveur](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14310/que-signifient-ces-dictons-sur-la-sainte-catherine/14313#comment27220_14313) !